# Neovim paste without overwriting register w/ Lua

Tags: vimscript, neovim, register, lua

So I know with vimscript you could make paste not overwrite your register with this:

```
vnoremap p pgvy
```

And I've tried a few ways to get this to with with Lua such as:

```
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', 'p', 'pgvy', { noremap = true })
```

But this doesn't work.

How can I get this kind of functionality with a Lua config?

Comment: FWIW, in modern vim `:help v_P`

Comment: I second that recommendation :)

Comment: Lol, well that's simple. Been wishing I could do this for years but just dealt with the "vp" functionality. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should do:

```
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('v', 'p', 'pgvy', { noremap = true })
```

The first argument is the mode:

- `n` for Normal (equivalent to `nnoremap`)
- `v` for Visual (equivalent to `vnoremap`)

But as Ben suggested you could also do:

```
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('v', 'p', 'P', { noremap = true })
```